# Enable/ disable button issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario where i have to enable/ disable button based on the checkboxes status. If the checkbox is already checked and status is file uploaded/ Saved as Draft then if user go and uncheck it all the 3 buttons should be enable if he check it back that checkbox only upload to portal will be enabled and save as draft and discard will be disabled. If all status is File uploaded then all three buttons will be disabled if there is no change on checkbox.

In Short if any change occur to those checkboxes, The buttons will enable otherwise they will go back to their previous state.

```js
let status = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
for (let i = 0; i < $("table tbody tr").length; i++) {
      let tableStatus = $("table tbody tr:eq(" + [i] + ") td:eq(1)").text();
      status.push(tableStatus);
      status.join(",");

    }
     if (status.indexOf("Saved as Draft") > -1) {
      $("#upload").prop('disabled', false);
      $("#discard, #save").prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });
 
 function doCheck(checkbox) {
  let newCheckedStatus = [];

  let nextVal = $(checkbox).parent().next().find(".docStatusCheck").val();
  $(checkbox).attr('data-change', 'yes');
  if ($(checkbox).is(':checked')) {
  
   
    $(checkbox).val("yes");
    $(checkbox).parent().next().text("Not Applicable");
    $("#discard, #save, #upload").prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    if (nextVal == undefined || nextVal == "") {
      $(checkbox).val("");
    } else {
      $(checkbox).val("no");
    }
    $(checkbox).parent().next().text("File Not Selected ");
    for (var i = 0; i < $("table tbody tr").length; i++) {
      let newCheckedValue = $("table tbody tr:eq(" + [i] + ") td:eq(1)").text();
      newCheckedStatus.push(newCheckedValue);
      newCheckedStatus.join(",");

    }
    if (status.indexOf("Saved as Draft") > -1) {
      $("#upload").prop('disabled', false);
      $("#discard, #save").prop('disabled', true);
    } else if (newCheckedStatus.indexOf("Not Applicable") > -1) {
      $("#discard, #save, #upload").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $("#discard, #save, #upload").prop('disabled', true);
    }
   
  }
}

function doUncheck(checkmark) {
  let newCheckedStatus = [];

  $(checkmark).attr('data-change', 'yes');
  if ($(checkmark).is(':checked')) {
    $(checkmark).val("yes");
    for (var i = 0; i < $("table tbody tr").length; i++) {
      let newCheckedValue = $("table tbody tr:eq(" + [i] + ") td:eq(2)").text();
      newCheckedStatus.push(newCheckedValue);
      newCheckedStatus.join(",");
    }
    if (status.indexOf("Saved as Draft") > -1) {
      $("#upload").prop('disabled', false);
      $("#discard, #save").prop('disabled', true);
    } else if (newCheckedStatus.indexOf("Not Applicable") > -1) {
      $("#discard, #save, #upload").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $("#discard, #save, #upload").prop('disabled', true);
    }
    $(checkmark).parent().next().find(".prevStatus").text("Not Applicable");

  } else {
    $(checkmark).next().val("no");
    $(checkmark).val("no");
    $("#discard, #save, #upload").prop('disabled', false);
    $(checkmark).parent().next().text("File Not Selected ");
   

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<table border=1>
<thead><tr><td></td><td>Status</td></tr></thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="Checkbox" onclick="doUncheck(this)" checked value="yes"></td>
    <td>File uploaded</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="Checkbox" checked value="yes" onclick="doUncheck(this)"></td>
    <td>File uploaded</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="Checkbox" onclick="doCheck(this)" value=""></td>
    <td>File not Selected</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="Checkbox" onclick="doUncheck(this)" checked value="yes"></td>
    <td>Saved as Draft</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="Checkbox" onclick="doUncheck(this)" checked value="yes"></td>
    <td>File uploaded</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="Checkbox" onclick="doUncheck(this)" checked value="yes"></td>
    <td>File uploaded</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button id="discard">
Discard
</button>
<button id="save">
Save as Draft
</button>
<button id="upload">
Upload
</button>
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uj1kzdv4/)

Comment: no, Issue is not resolved, but errors in console i have cleared. You can run the above snippet

Comment: yes, but i cannot change those status.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're even asking - so I'll remove my comments and leave it to others

Comment: if already checked checkbox is uncheck or uncheck checkbox is check that moment all buttons should be enable. You can try unchecking three in a row and again check one again. That time you will see only upload to portal is enable. But technically all buttons has to enable because still two are uncheck

Comment: `if already checked checkbox is uncheck or uncheck checkbox is check that moment all buttons should be enable` ... in other words, changing the state of any checkbox, regardless of its state, all buttons should be enabled?